# Can't access a property with <html:checkbox property="..."> when iterating a list

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1, html

In my Struts form I've got a list. In a JSP I iterate over it like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${MyForm.types}" var="type">
    <tr>
        <td>${type.name}</td>
        <td>${type.forced}</td>
        <td>${type.receive}</td>
        <html:checkbox property="type.receive" />
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Now the `<html:checkbox` isn't working. I'm always getting the following error:

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method for property type.receive of bean org.apache.struts.taglib.html.BEAN
```

But actually there is a getter for this property in my form class. It's written like this:

```
public Boolean getReceive() {
  return receive;
}
```

When I remove the checkbox it's also possible to display the property as in the `<td>`-tag above so I don't know where the problem is.

Maybe I'm accessing it in the wrong way?

Comment: I don't do Struts, but the the error message is basically telling you that there's no `getFalse()` method. This must give new insights. Maybe you need `<html:checkbox bean="auspraegung" property="cbx_uebernehmen">` or to iterate with `<logic:iterate>` instead or so.

Comment: Sorry, that was the wrong error message. I've appended the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now doing it like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${MyForm.testList}" var="testElement" varStatus="status">
    <html:checkbox property="testList[${status.count-1}].checkboxValue" />
</c:forEach>
```

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062350/is-it-possible-to-access-say-the-3rd-element-in-a-collection-with-struts).

Answer (score 0):

All the individual properties type in struts Action form should be String.You have to define cbx_uebernehmen as String Type.

Comment: No, I don't think so. I'm already using a `<html:radio>`-tag with a boolean property and it works. See http://struts.apache.org/1.2.7/userGuide/struts-html.html#checkbox for more information ("[...] The underlying property value associated with this field should be of type boolean [...]").

Comment: This is certainly incorrect advice. Action form can contain variables of types other than String.

Answer (score 0):

I think your getter method should look like this (is... instead of get...) :

```
public Boolean isCbx_uebernehmen() {
  return cbx_uebernehmen;
}
```

Should work like that. If it still doesn't, try changing return datatype from `Boolean` to `boolean`.

Comment: It's a `Boolean` property, not `boolean`. Regardless, the Javabean spec allows both, it would have been a bug in Struts otherwise.

Comment: Yep, didn't think it would really make any difference either, but just thought it could be worth a try if it still didn't work for some reason. I think the problem is because of the naming.

Comment: Hm, then again, Struts user guide (linked by Bernhard V in his comment to another answer) does state "The underlying property value associated with this field should be of type **boolean**."

Comment: It didn't work with boolean from the beginning, so I switched to Boolean. Nevertheless, in the same form there is a Boolean property which I can use without a problem in a `<html:checkbox>`. It also has a "get"-getter.