# Is it possible to access say the 3rd element in a collection with Struts?

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1

Is there a way to do the following thing in Struts / JSP?

```
<html:checkbox property="list.get(0).checked" />
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access the 3rd element in a list in JSTL, the syntax is just like arrays:

```
<html:checkbox property="list[2].checked" />
```

Note that if you are new to JSTL/EL you'll have to add the appropriate jar to your classpath and reference the tag library.

Comment: Thank you. And if I want to create a checkbox that sets the 3rd element of a collection? I think your code example would get my the value of the element, wouldn't it?

Comment: Ok, it worked. `<html:checkbox property="list[3].checked" />`

Comment: Cool.  I wasn't sure whatever was in your list had a checked property or not, so just left it out.  I'll update my answer.